# Can't get rotation on a custom Angular element

Tags: html, css, animation, rotation

I've used the following CSS taken from [here](https://codepen.io/vitoralberto/pen/OPYyYB).

```
:host {
  animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
  border: 10px solid yellow;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(359deg); }
}
```

I don't get to see any rotation, although I can see the border, so I know that I target the correct element. I don't think it's required to have an IMG (and mine is a custom thingy in Angular). It works on the IMG and also on a DIV. Not sure how to diagnose it further as rotations/animations aren't my strongest suite.

One approach is to put the custom component in a DIV and rotate that. However, it does rotate around the middle of the screen (wiiiide circle) instead of spinning around itself.

```
<div id="loading">
  <my-icon-globe></my-icon-globe>
</div>

#loading { animation: rotation 2s infinite linear; }

@keyframes rotation {
  from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg); }
}
```

Comment: I guess you may adjust the `transform-origin` if you are going to attempt the second approach (put the custom component in a DIV)

Comment: @AluminiumShek Ah, I found [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform-origin/). Thanks! However, *center center* nor *left top* roates around **itself**. Is it customary to specify the offset by fixed number of pixels (as a half of the object's size)?

Comment: Yes you can. Know more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

Comment: @AluminiumShek You might want to post it as an answer t be accepted.

Comment: Thank you. I've posted it as answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) of the DIV if you attempt the second approach.